# Pygame rotation trouble

Tags: python, pygame

Recently began a new pygame project, asteroids. I've been working on getting an image to rotate in the direction of the cursor, which i'm finding irritatingly hard. Any help is appreciated, here is the code for the rotation so far:

```
import sys, pygame, math, time;
from pygame.locals import *;
spaceship = ('spaceship.png')
mouse_c = ('crosshair.png')
backg = ('background.jpg')
fire_beam = ('beam.png')
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
bk = pygame.image.load(backg).convert_alpha()
mousec = pygame.image.load(mouse_c).convert_alpha()
space_ship = pygame.image.load(spaceship).convert_alpha()
f_beam = pygame.image.load(fire_beam).convert_alpha()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
x, y = 357, 300 #position of space_ship, (line 38 btw, second from bottom)
while True:
screen.blit(bk, (0, 0))
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
        print("Left Button Pressed")
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
        print("Right Button Pressed")
    if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
        clock.tick(60)
        x1, y1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x2, y2 = x, y
        dx, dy = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
        rads = math.atan2(dx, dy)
        degs = math.degrees(rads)
        pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship, (degs))
        print degs #Prints correct output..
        pygame.display.update() #the image flickers, but does not rotate
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
screen.blit(mousec, (pos))
screen.blit(space_ship, (375, 300))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: So... What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Please, fix identation. It is not an optional thing in Python. As it stands, there is a syntax error after the `while True` line

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html): "A Surface transform is an operation that moves or resizes the pixels. All these functions take a Surface to operate on and return a new Surface with the results."

As it is, you operate the transform, but throw away the result.
You could just change the line

```
pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship, (degs))
```

to:

```
space_ship = pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship, (degs))
```

In order to see it working, but it would not be a good :
 you'd  need to re-calculate your degrees to have only the difference
in degrees from one iteration to the next - but worse, successive raster-picture
transforms would degenerate your spaceship into an amorphous blob of pixels very fast.

The right thing to do is to keep a reference to your original spacehsip pictures, and always rotate that instead.

So, before your main loop, you do:
    space_ship_image = pygame.image.load(spaceship).convert_alpha()
And inside the loop, the aforementioned:

```
space_ship = pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship_image, (degs))
```

BTW, raster artifacts being what they are, yo probably will want to use a larger
version of your ship in your "spaceship.png" file, and use "rotozoom" instead of "rotate",
scaling down as you rotate the ship to get your final image.